# Jackson deserialize generic with unknown property name

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have following `JSON`. And I am parsing it using  `Jackson` Parser

```
 {
  "code": 0,
  "response": {
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "limit": 20,
        "count": 5,
        "pageCount": 1
    },
   "random": [
      ....
     ]
  }
}
```

Now I have simple  `POJO`  classes created for various `random` object. I expect 3-4 different types of  `random`  object. So instead of creating different wrapper classes for different types of 'random' object I created a generic one

**EDITED CLASS:**

```
public class PaginatedResponse<E> {

   private Pagination pagination;
   private List<E> responseList;

   public Pagination getPagination() {
       return pagination;
   }

   public void setPagination(Pagination pagination) {
       this.pagination = pagination;
   }

   public List<E> getResponseList() {
       return responseList;
   }

   public void setResponseList(List<E> responseList) {
       this.responseList = responseList;
   }
}
```

Now For mapping it I used,

```
  JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(response);
  TypeReference<PaginatedResponse<LocationParent>> ref = new TypeReference<PaginatedResponse<LocationParent>>() {   };
  PaginatedResponse<LocationParent> resp = mapper.convertValue(tree.get("response"), ref);
```

But i am not able to map `responseList`. I get the  `pagination`  object but the `responseList` is always null. Now how to dynamically provide `property name` for `responseList`.

Please help

Comment: Generic wrapper works fine, as long as you pass non-generic type when deserializing (otherwise Jackson does not know type of 'random' beyond it being java.lang.Object). This can be done by passing `TypeReference`, or if it's fully dynamic, using `TypeFactory.constructGenericType()` (or whatever the exact name is). But you should not require custom deserializer as long as there is a POJO for 'random'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping in all my previous questions also. I followed your advice and used `TypeReference`. Have updated my question.

Comment: So far so good! What is the missing part here?

Comment: `responseList` is null, the `random` list returned is not mapped into `reponseList`. If I provide a property name for `responseList` it gets mapped. But since its a generic and it has different property name for different responses, How to provide `property name` dynamically??

Comment: For that generic type will not help, and what you really need is polymorphic type handling. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need for variable value type is handling for polymorphic types. Generic types alone won't help, since deserialization side would not know what type to use.

You can enable polymorphic type handling with annotation `@JsonTypeInfo`; but a problem in this particular case is that you want a `List` of things of arbitrary type -- due to type-erasure, all Java Lists are really just `List<Object>`; there is no typing for elements.

If it was me, I would probably sub-class `PaginatedResponse` and just add `@JsonTypeInfo` in base class, like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(...) // see javadocs for properties needed
public abstract class PaginatedResponse<T> {
  public Pagination pagination;
  // .. and so on
}

public class PaginatedFooResponse<Foo> { }
```

The reason to use sub-classing here is simply make it possible for deserializer to figure out element type, given type of response object. Response object will have type (`PaginatedFooResposne`), and from that type of elements is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
JSONObject objJSON = JSONObject.fromString("urString");

String code = objJSON.get("code");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want `PaginatedResponse POJO` and don't want to create it manually by using JsonNode. I know this will work. but i am looking for a better way. Will wait before accepting it as answer.